# OpenFrameworks video stream i/o

Tags: video-streaming, openframeworks

I am working on a project in OpenFrameworks that is going to require figuring out streaming video between two machines both ways.

I am not even sure where to start, and I'm not finding much by searching. OfxOgg for example looks like it only outputs a stream. I am also wondering if it is the sort of thing that I could just hijack a networking add-on to do. If so, which one?

Mini update: I'm looking in to ofxFileTransfer. After reading other posts about people trying to do MJPEG, i came across one where they ended up abandoning "video" and just transferring still images and swapping the buffer as fast as the files would transfer. That might be an okay solution for me. Maybe.

Still, some advice on the subject would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, assuming you can work on OSX, would be to use [Syphon](http://syphon.v002.info/) to Quartz Composer, then the 1024 Architecture network [send/receive](https://1024d.wordpress.com/2010/06/18/_1024_network-sendreceive-quartzcomposer-plugin/) patch between two computers QC patches, then Syphon back to oF on the second machine...

Comment: I have heard of Syphon before but hadn't considered its use. That's an interesting idea. I wonder if I could get Syphon to point directly to the OpenGL textures that are already in my OF shader...? (that's another thread) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: fyi, I saw a few new issues in the Syphon Googlecode database today about sending between machines - looks like they will start working on that soon!

Answer (score 0):

Are the two machines in the same place or do you need to stream over the internet?

If they are in the same place, I would recommend to send video data with UDP. There are two excellent examples already in openFrameworks called `networkUdpSenderExample` and `networkUdpReceiverExample`. You can browse their code [here](https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/examples/addons). they are sending/receiving only strings, but I think it would be not that hard to send video with it.

If they are connected over the internet, you could try to use the examples for TCP, but TCP has more overhead than UDP.

Comment: For my particular use, I will likely be able to connect the computers together with hard wire network cable which, i agree, is a lot simpler. I'm welcoming all options though. I didn't see another good question on StackOverflow for this subject yet, so I left it a little open ended. Thanks for the tip!